# Find all movies that are considered Action or Adventure and return only the title of the movie in NoSQL

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am not to sure of what to do. I tried combining $and & $or syntax but my code keeps coming up wrong. I have tried projection. and have a feeling I may need to run the queries separate.

This is the last code I have tried running in VS code in the mongodb playground:

```
db.movies.find(
    { $and : [
        { $or : [  { genre: { $eq: "Action" } }, { genre: $eq:"Adventure"},
        { $or : [ { title: "Wonder Woman" }, { title: 1 },
        { $or : [ { title: "Cloud Atlas" }, { title: 1 },
        { $or : [ { title: "Pan's Labyrinth"}, { title: 1 },
        { $or : [ { title: "Gone With the Wind"}, { title: 1 },
        { $or : [ { title: "Spaceballs"}, { title: 1 },
        { $or : [ { title: "Silence of the Lambs"}, { title: 1 },
        { $or : [ { title: "American History X"}, { title: 1 },
        { $or : [ { title: "Psycho"}, { title: 1 },
        { $or : [ { title: "The Pianist"}, { title: 1 },
        { $or : [ { title: "Gladiator"},{ title: 1 } } ] }
    ]}
)
```

can any one assist with what I may be doing wrong and what I could do?

Comment: please add some sample json input and your expected output

Answer (score 0):

You are just mixing the `project` object which is in charge of returning only certain fields and the `query` object which is in charge of filtering documents.

Here is how it'll look fixed:

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      genre: "Action"
    },
    {
      genre: "Adventure"
    }
  ]
},
{
  _id: 0,
  title: 1
})
```

You can also clean it up a little and use the [$in](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator instead:

```
db.collection.find({
  genre: {
    $in: [
      "Action",
      "Adventure"
    ]
  }
},
{
  _id: 0,
  title: 1
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8BRrPGJtK_x)